# How to display annotations that are within a set distance (Swift 4.0)

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am trying to display all bus stops within 1km on annotations, however, the UIMap is showing annotations that are not within 1km. When I change to 10km, it will show annotations more than 1km away, but not near enough.

class Value: Codable {
   let busStopCode, roadName, description: String
   let latitude, longitude: Double

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case busStopCode = "BusStopCode"
    case roadName = "RoadName"
    case description = "Description"
    case latitude = "Latitude"
    case longitude = "Longitude"
}

init(busStopCode: String, roadName: String, description: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    self.busStopCode = busStopCode
    self.roadName = roadName
    self.description = description
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
}
func GetDistance(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) -> Double {
    let selectedCoordinate = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let busStopCoordinate = CLLocation(latitude: Double(self.latitude), longitude: self.longitude)

    return busStopCoordinate.distance(from: selectedCoordinate)
}
```

ViewController class

```
@IBAction func GPSTrack(_ sender: Any) {
    InputAllAnnotation(busStops: stopSearchResults)
    print("Searching for nearby bus stops")
}

func InputAllAnnotation(busStops: [Value]) {
    for busStop in busStops{
        let busStopObj = BusStopAnnotation(value: busStop)
        Annotations.append(busStopObj)

        let distance = busStop.GetDistance(latitude: Double(currentLocation?.latitude ?? 0), longitude: Double(currentLocation?.longitude ?? 0))
        if  distance < 10000 {
            mapView.addAnnotation(busStopObj)
        }
    }
}
```

I get bus stops annotated at 10km away, but not within 1km
[image: Image of annotations on Map]

Comment: What does `busStop.getDistance()` do?  Can you show that code?  Also, you should probably add a `guard` statement to `InputAllAnnotations` (which should be called `inputAllAnnotations`) to return if `currentLocation` is `nil` (or better yet, disable the button if you have no location).  Also, why create a `BusStopAnnotation` if you aren't going to use it? - Create the annotation within your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

check distance from busStops and you(or any value)

```
//for 1km
let distance = myLocation.distance(from: busStopLocation) / 1000
```

then check for the busStop

```
if  distance <= 0.1{

self.displayAlert(title: "INFO", message: "BUS STOP NEAR 1KM")
}
```

check distance for busStop 10km

```
let distance = myLocation.distance(from: busStopLocation) / 10000
```

if  distance > 0.1{

```
self.displayAlert(title: "INFO", message: "BUS STOP AT 10KM")
}
```

Comment: I identified my problem with this! Ahaha thank you very much :)